# How to have variable callback types based on an input parameter in a PubSub pattern?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I’m creating this simple pubsub. Is there a way to have variable CallbackData based on the Name you subscribe to?

```
type Names = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'
type CallbackData = {
  a?: { foo: number },
  b?: { foo: boolean },
  c?: { foo: string }
}
type Callback = (props: CallbackData) => any;

class PubSub {
  subscribers: {
    [key in Names]: Callback[];
  } = {} as any

  subscribe = (name: Names, callback: Callback) => {
    function ensureArray<T>(value?: Callback[]): Callback[] {
      if (!Array.isArray(value)) value = []
      return value;
    }
    const subscribers = ensureArray(this.subscribers[name]);
    subscribers.push(callback)
  }

  publish = (name: Names, data: CallbackData) => {
    const subscribers = this.subscribers[name]
    subscribers.forEach((subscriber) => subscriber(data))
  }
}

const ps = new PubSub()
ps.subscribe('bar', ({ a }) => console.log(a.foo));
ps.publish('bar', { a: { foo: 0 }});
```

So basically here I wanna say in typescript what elements you can expect in the callback object based on what you subscribe to.

Just for example:

- If you subscribe to `bar` you’ll always have `{ a: { foo: number } }` and nothing else.
- If you subscribe to `foo` you’ll have all of them available
- If you subscribe to `baz` you’ll have only `b` and `c` i.e. `{ b: {…}; c: {…} }`

Bonus: Is it possible to declare the types in such a smart way that it picks it up in the `ps.subscribe` from the definitions of `ps.publish`? If not and maps need to be written that’s ok.

Thank you!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQRd7N) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I think `assertIsArray` is not a good fn name here, as so named function would be expected to return `asserts value is any[]` i.e throw a error if it's not. Consider naming it `ensureArray` or something

Comment: @jcalz thank you! This is absolutely awesome! Add it as a response and I’ll accept!

Comment: Okay I will do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to represent your mapping from `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, to the expected callback data type somewhere.  First, let's remove the [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) modifier from `CallbackData`'s properties

```
interface CallbackData {
    a: { foo: number },
    b: { foo: boolean },
    c: { foo: string }
}
```

and then define the required mapping in terms of it:

```
interface NameMapping {
    foo: CallbackData;
    bar: Pick<CallbackData, "a">;
    baz: Pick<CallbackData, "b" | "c">
}
```

And for ease of discussion we can make your `Callback` type [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the expected data type:

```
type Callback<T> = (data: T) => any;
```

---

Now we can give strong typings to `PubSub`:

```
class PubSub {
    subscribers: { [K in keyof NameMapping]?: 
      Callback<NameMapping[K]>[] } = {}

    subscribe = <K extends keyof NameMapping>(
      name: K, 
      callback: Callback<NameMapping[K]>
    ) => {
        const subscribers: Callback<NameMapping[K]>[] = 
          (this.subscribers[name] ??= []);
        subscribers.push(callback);
    }

    publish = <K extends keyof NameMapping>(
      name: K, 
      data: NameMapping[K]
    ) => {
        const subscribers: Callback<NameMapping[K]>[] = 
          this.subscribers[name] ?? [];
        subscribers.forEach((subscriber) => subscriber(data));
    }
}
```

The `subscribers` field is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `NameMapping`, where each property is an optional array of `Callback<>` for the relevant data type.

Then `subscribe` and `publish` are both generic methods in `K`, the type of the `name` parameter, and then the subsequent parameter is given the appropriate related type: `Callback<NameMapping[K]>>` for the `callback` parameter of `subscribe`, and `NameMapping[K]` for the `data` parameter of `publish`.

I did change the implementations of these methods slightly, using [nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) and [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) to handle the case where `this.subscribers[name]` is undefined.  In both cases we substitute an empty array of the expected type, and the only difference is that `subscribe` actually assigns that empty array back to the property before using it.

---

Let's make sure it works:

```
const ps = new PubSub()
ps.subscribe('bar', ({ a }) => console.log(a.foo));
// (property) PubSub.subscribe: <"bar">(
//    name: "bar", callback: Callback<Pick<CallbackData, "a">>) => void
ps.publish('bar', { a: { foo: 0 } }); // 0
// (property) PubSub.publish: <"bar">(
//    name: "bar", data: Pick<CallbackData, "a">) => void

ps.subscribe("baz", ({ a, b, c }) => console.log(a, b, c)); // error!
// ------------------> ~
// Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Pick<CallbackData, "b" | "c">'.

ps.publish("baz", { a: { foo: 0 }, b: { foo: true }, c: { foo: "" } }); // error!
// ---------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//   Object literal may only specify known properties, and
// 'a' does not exist in type 'Pick<CallbackData, "b" | "c">'.
```

Looks good.  When you call the methods, the `name` argument constrains the subsequent argument, and you get the behavior you want.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrABAYWQG1wEZoDWAIstMhgN6gb0bIBcNGiA9uy5AK4C2BBBgC+AGjoMCLam04sCnXLGSQR4kAwyppsrhgDO0eFADmI0MNAQYCFOgwA5ZH1gBZZAAcPpmhPoc9HHwiVDIKZABuPwwieBYABXBQgB4gwhJySlEMACJkHIA+KI1JZAAvBKTiVLx00MzkbJyCHIwAH1zUQosrEGgATw9MNJDqgBUCjABeDAAKABNwljGASmnJlX7i0FRcZH19DHieAgBlE98S+n0T-VRjQXh9HQBtAGkMKAxiWH72REczjcnm8kBMAF0APwsEYkZJOFzuLymd7ggovcEiaY0SxgK4GW73cCCbHJD6wAAecEg80OPz+AIRwORYIKs0gQJYb2yqFqoxhfLhTKRoJMqIKaymk1o+M0qHYkEMBIIdweCGe2EFKWFIJRbzRGOxs2gAAtwPoAHQ3FVEx76F4clyYyGQmYYlbFTSaa2q4nqi0eHj6E2zXnBEge6K46KBgi4c0m0nkqmwGl037-QGI3Ws9mcjDcjCLSgsHUssX6yXS6JyhVKn229UC8PaoEivUGzEzU3mq2EtVPB1A52QjAYmsMBsDy0ceAAUTQIdmU798Cryt9jwW4RWKyjPTx8sV0AwHkOM0gsAA7kcTucCLM9yAz32bWrZgByWIf7KzGRUYR1yPfR2CUC1cHYExZmQC0Al3YoAHoELmDx4HYIZ4AGNZjjOE5X03WAWGSZpkHgQpZlAJDNEdQjcliHIeS1YhmzqapEhSWF6nCJp8gKCV1gwAA3dhwHmUAX1jeNg0-b9sn-HQAhYAAGLFAIiDAqKUyjkNmVD0IQLDb1wggAxOKSTSIkiyLZbTqPzKyGKLJYjiqGoWzCLJcl49dhNE3oXxXQRZhIspHL-RhsgIHkRCAutQNgcDIOgyKeXgjTkIQND4AAQlsgBaArCqK4rCsmAA-Wz4jQjCBgwD9kA-It2FgQ5IHYE9KXNE8FQwAYhjq9jqk4jzGjo1oOhyLoCg-C1-MtSSE2CohQrkxgFLkDAVLEGJ1r0IweEwbbtFYRTclaYQYvUqjMvYHL8pKh68vKsqXtet6Xts+gAHkCAAK1gVAT3jOB4DwDA+GQfoMAVXAof0IZUHARAoeINqr1UPSavAFrshUMSQCo+rGvmZrWvajBOqVL4+swD9Brc1iGiaFp2k6QoZt6XogA)